TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable with Plotly Choropleth
I am trying to make a choropleth map from county level FIPS data using this example from plotly.
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/minoritymajority.csv')
df_sample_r = df_sample[df_sample['STNAME'] == 'Florida']

values = df_sample_r['TOT_POP'].tolist()
fips = df_sample_r['FIPS'].tolist()

endpts = list(np.mgrid[min(values):max(values):4j])
colorscale = ["#030512","#1d1d3b","#323268","#3d4b94","#3e6ab0",
              "#4989bc","#60a7c7","#85c5d3","#b7e0e4","#eafcfd"]
fig = ff.create_choropleth(
    fips=fips, values=values, scope=['Florida'], show_state_data=True,
    colorscale=colorscale, binning_endpoints=endpts, round_legend_values=True,
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
    legend_title='Population by County',
    county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5},
    exponent_format=True,
)
fig.layout.template = None
fig.show()

When I run this code as is I get TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not iterable.
I see in this post from a year ago that recommends either downgrading Shapely, which I could not get to work still, or to "Access the MultiPolygon's 'geoms' property". I'm new to working with plotly and geo data and find this answer unintuitive. I am wondering if someone could suggest how to edit the code to make this work or is there some other way to solve this issue?

Do you mean you don't understand the original answers or that you understand them but don't want to use the geoms property?

I also don't understand the accepted answer in the post linked to, as the problem is in the create_choropleth function, not in your code. However, this function has been deprecated for quite a while and the last update of plotly-geo was 5 years ago, so I would look for another solution. In the plotly documentation the advise is given to use another approach, explained here. Have you/can you try that?

@Pieter That approached you linked worked out using the plotly express version, thanks for finding this.

The create_choropleth function has been deprecated for quite a while and the last update of plotly-geo that is used for it was 5 years ago, so I would look for another solution.
Plotting choropleth maps is now available in plotly.express. An elaborate list of examples can be found here.
